# Eclipse emulator dpi can not be set over 320dpi ?

Tags: android, resolution

You must define dpi on your emulator. 240 is hdpi, 160 is mdpi and below that are usually ldpi.

Extract from Android Developer Guide link above:

320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

It means 320dp is xhdpi but in eclipse, we can not set 480dp or any further value. so how would i set (abstracted lcd density) to 480dp or above it?

Comment: wait, here 320 dp is width of screen. dp is density independent pixels and dpi is density per inch. Both are different things. 320 dp does not mean xhdpi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//actually you get confused

here you mentions 320,480,600 and 720 is width of the device in portrait mode.

//this image show how to create 320dp screen as 240 as hdpi or you can make it for 320 xhdpi emulator
[image]

**Note:** here 213dpi is new tvdpi for nexus 7 devices.