# Increate density of android emulator

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

When I increase density of honeycomb emulator then it show always 160, I want to create extra high density emulator. How to create it?

Comment: what do you mean density? Ru confused with resolution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11735766/1012284

Comment: check it http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/

Comment: Screen density
The quantity of pixels within a physical area of the screen; usually referred to as dpi (dots per inch). For example, a "low" density screen has fewer pixels within a given physical area, compared to a "normal" or "high" density screen.
For simplicity, Android groups all actual screen densities into four generalized densities: low, medium, high, and extra high.

Comment: By default density is 160, I want to set it to 320.