# Android tablet in Emulator is not picking up the right layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am new to Android and trying to learn how to use the multiple layout folders to specify different layouts for different sized devices.

I have tried a few different things, but nothing seems to work to get my emulated tablet to use the larger layout.

My layout directory structure is:

- layout
- layout-large
- layout-sw600dp
- layout-xlarge

The main.xml in "layout" is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    <SearchView android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/EarthquakeFragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

The main.xml in the other three folders is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <SearchView android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFF"/>

    <fragment android:name="com.paad.earthquake.EarthquakeListFragment"
              android:id="@+id/EarthquakeListFragment"
              android:layout_width="360dp"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />

    <fragment android:name="com.paad.earthquake.EarthquakeMapFragment"
              android:id="@+id/EarthquakeMapFragment"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

The emulator setup is trying to emulate the Google Nexus 7:

- Target: Google APIs (API level 16)
- Skin: WXGA800-7in
- SD Card: 16M
- I'm using all of the other options that come with the skin, plus hw.keyboard=yes and hw.ramSize=512

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: nexus 7 is large tvdpi devices so it will pick from layout-large that your supplied. so whats wrong? what is not working?

Comment: It is using the main.xml from the standard "layout" directory, not the "layout-large" or "layout-sw600dp" directory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11735766/1012284 RU sure that you choose Abstract LCS density as  213dpi?

Comment: @PadmaKumar, the WXGA800-7in image already does that for you. Actually, it sets it automatically to 213 to better emulate the Nexus 7. ;-)

Comment: @DavidCesarino you are right. but I can change the value to 160 so that it will pick from normal layout folder, that was my doubt :-))

Comment: Yes, true. I was not correcting you, also because he didn't provide enough details to exactly pinpoint his issue (that was my point: so many things could be wrong in this question --- we need more details).

Comment: The hw.lcd.density=213 for my AVD and hw.gpu.enabled=yes, if that makes a difference

Comment: What other details would be helpful for identifying the problem?  I wasn't sure what all was needed.  Thanks!

Comment: I had an idea, not sure if it will work. Try setting the screen size to 7 inches when starting the emulator. It's in the Launch Options window, right before starting it (not when creating the emulator image).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a 10" tablet and android 3.2 or above, you should have layout-sw720dp folder to have your layout file